# Challenges where the code itself is not important

Tags: discussion

Please have a look at [this Sandbox submission](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10547/31516). Regardless, this question is a general one, not about the Sandbox submission specifically.

Very short summary of the question:

Build/design a controller that can perform a given operation using as few function blocks as possible. The controller has only a few possible functions (logical functions (`AND`, `OR`, `NOR` ...) and a pulse generator.

Now, the real challenge here is to find the best controller design, not the actual implementation.

Is this question on-topic? Is it a good challenge?

I've found [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37648/drive-a-hexadecimal-7-segment-display-using-nand-logic-gates/37675#37675) very similar question, but I would claim they're not duplicates.

For the record: The Sandbox submission had +2 when I asked this question. We'll see how the Meta-effect goes. =)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10287/are-non-programming-golf-puzzles-allowed?noredirect=1&lq=1) [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/do-all-challenges-have-to-be-answered-with-code?noredirect=1&lq=1) [Related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/objective-computational-challenges-without-code).  I'm pretty sure the answer is yes.